# Parent root folder domain in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The way I desgined my express nodejs application as per below;

```
app.get('/', page.index);
 //Add new,edit and delete form
app.get('/approval', page.approval);
//Task to approve/reject the subordinate form
app.get('/task', page.task);
//Report
app.get('/report', page.report);
//Admin
app.get('/admin', page.admin)
app.listen(3000);
```

Hence I can always access  using the url i.e

```
http://<Servername>:3000/ 
http://<Servername>:3000/approval     
http://<Servername>:3000/task
```

Lets say now I will need to have a parent app root as  appsA ( ie.

```
http://<Servername>:3000/appsA/
http://<Servername>:3000/appsA/approval
http://<Servername>:3000/appsA/task
```

How can I do that from express/nodejs without go and add appsA as a url on each of the get request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use router to do that, example

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', page.index);

router.get('/approval', page.approval);

router.get('/task', page.task);

router.get('/report', page.report);

router.get('/admin', page.admin)

// Then implement root route path 

app.use("/appsA", router);
```

**Note:** Routers are only available for Express 4 and above, This solution will not work on all Express versions below version 4, If you still want to do this with express 3, you can implement your own `Router` middleware

Comment: this is exist only on express 4? how about express 3

Comment: @Fairul.. you have middleware in express 3.. you can use them.. and for express 4.. this answer is good

Comment: @NaeemShaikh are you suggesting express.directory in express 3?

Comment: @Fairul.. no I am suggesting `app.use`, you can still create your own Router middle ware and make this answer work for Express 3..

Comment: In express3 you have to create new express app instance of using route

```
var router = express();
// Do stuff
app.use('/appA', router);
```

But for that we have to re-implement same middlewares on both app, so I not recommend

Comment: @greenlikeorange doesnt work for me in express3..any alternative?

Comment: @Fairul I not very sure but in express3 app.routes will return get all routes relative with you can configure root app route in there.

https://gist.github.com/greenlikeorange/5fa069bc0c2001f9bd84